# How to tell if my server REQUIRES ECC RAM?

Tags: memory, ecc

I know ECC is recommended for servers, but do certain pieces of hardware REQUIRE you to have it? If so, which component? e.g: CPU, motherboard

Comment: The motherboard drives this requirement

Comment: So this is a requirement then? as in, my server will not function without ECC?

Comment: You can only determine that.  You asked, "do certain hardware required ECC memory", my response is that the motherboard drives that requirement.  There are no CPUs on the market that only work on "server" hardware. No; my comment isn't worthy of being an answer

Comment: arent  "The motherboard drives this requirement" &
"There are no CPUs on the market that only work on "server" hardware"
conflicting statements?

Comment: Nope; I was pointing out that CPU can't possibly drive this requirement since Xeons (most typically installed on "server" motherboards) can be used in non-server form factors

Comment: Worth pointing out that some file systems also work better with ECC memory due to how they handle bit-rot and error checking.  If you want an answer, be specific,  I know you want to know if you need ECC memory I just can't answer that question since your details are not specific enough

Comment: in summation:
Is having ECC RAM a requirement set by the motherboard? meaning, if i do not have ECC RAM, will my server not function like a regular computer?

Comment: Your system will not post if the motherboard only supports ecc memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your system will not post if the motherboard only supports ecc memory.